# Get enum value from ComboBox and store it in integer?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, combobox

I have a collection of enums storing the zip codes of some cities.

```cs
public enum cities_zip
{
    Emsdetten = 48282,
    Berlin = 12345,
    Rheine = 48369,
}
```

I have a combobox which is getting filled with the `enum`s like this:

```
combo_cities.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(cities_zip));
```

Yet when I choose for example Berlin, it isn't getting stored as integer.

```
int zipcode = combo_cities.SelectedValue;
```

It says "Cannot convert type object to int".

If I do it like this:

```
int zipcode = Convert.ToInt32(combo_cities.SelectedValue);
```

the value of the integer is "0" regardless which city I choose.

Using `SelectedIndex` shows up at -1 regardless which city I choose, too.

Using `SelectedItem` doesn't work either (shows up as "0" too).

Any tips?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is winforms, right? What you're describing, a SelectedIndex of -1, sounds like there's no selected item. In test code that's identical as far as I can tell (and there's not much to it), this is working for me: In SelectedIndexChanged, `int x = (int)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;` gets me the int value of the selected enum value.

Comment: When using an enum, `SelectedValue` will give you `Enum.ToString()`, while `(int)SelectedValue` will return the associated value (an `int`, here). In this case, the same applies to `SelectedIem`. If you get a `SelectedIndex = -1` after a selection, then you're doing something wrong that is not shown here.

Comment: @Jimi That's not the case with SelectedValue. If `ValueMember` isn't set, it'll return the actual enum value, same as SelectedItem.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Re-reading the comment, I probably expressed the *concept* too loosely. Both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` return an Enum as an object. If you *inspect* it or *print* it, you'll see `[Enum].ToString()`. You can get the associated value casting it to its value type.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, that's much clearer.

Comment: As a note (probably completely useless), you can convert the Enumerator to `Dictionary<int, string>`: `var dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(cities_zip)).OfType<cities_zip>().ToDictionary(enu => (int)enu, enu => enu.ToString());`. Now, you can set: `combo_cities.DisplayMember = "Value"; combo_cities.ValueMember = "Key";`, and get the `int` value with from the `SelectedValue` property and the string representation with `combo_cities.GetItemText(combo_cities.SelectedItem)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this example will help to understand:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CityName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CityValue";
        comboBox1.DataSource = ListOfCities();
    }
    public List<City> ListOfCities()
    {
        List<City> list = new List<City>();
        foreach (cities_zip city in Enum.GetValues(typeof(cities_zip)))
        {
            City newCity = new City();
            newCity.CityName = city.ToString();
            newCity.CityValue = (int)city;
            list.Add(newCity);
        }
            return list;
    }
}    
public class City
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CityValue { get; set; }
}
public enum cities_zip
{
    Emsdetten = 48282,
    Berlin = 12345,
    Rheine = 48369,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `(int)combo_cities.SelectedValue` will work.

But also you need to check if `SelectedIndex` is different from -1, as it would mean that no item is selected. Something like this:

```
if( combo_cities.SelectedIndex > -1)
    var selectedIntValue = (int)combo_cities.SelectedValue;
```

For above to work you must call:

```
foreach (Subject s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(cities_zip)).Cast<cities_zip>())
    cbxSubject.Items.Add(s);
```

instead of setting `DataSource` property.